# Writeln is not working the right way it should

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I am new to Lazarus and trying to write some basic code:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    // Hier können Sie private Mitglieder deklarieren, wenn benötigt.
  public
    // Hier können Sie öffentliche Mitglieder deklarieren, wenn benötigt.
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  jame: string;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

begin
  writeln(jame);

end.
```

The problem is that it is showing this error:

[image]

It would be nice if someone were able to help me.

Comment: Your app is a GUI app, but you seem to want a console app.

Comment: In order to get help - please describe what you are trying to achieve.  You may want to output text to stdout or you may want to write something to a file (or maybe something else)... It is not obvious from your code.

Comment: No console was defined. Hence an `Einouterror` was raised. WriteLn is working as expected. I think you should change the title of the question to make it clear what your problem was.

Comment: so i cant console input something?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I Just changed the Project file to "Programm" and it worked.
[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows otherwise and it clearly shows **Program** (not "_Programm_"). Also were you just new to Lazarus or Pascal in general? Because using `TForm` is a strong indicator of having a GUI project instead of a console one.

Answer (score 2):

Newcomers usually have `EInOutError` on Windows, because a Win32 Lazarus application does not comes with a console by default. So, you must define it yourself.

### Option 1 - Keep your graphical application and output to some file

```
unit windows.output;

{$mode ObjFPC}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

  procedure Print(S : string);

implementation

const
  DebugOutputFilename : string = 'DebugOutput.txt';

var
  DebugOutput : TextFile;

procedure Print(S: string);
begin
  WriteLn(DebugOutput, S);
  System.Flush(DebugOutput);
end;

initialization
  AssignFile(DebugOutput, DebugOutputFilename);
  if FileExists(DebugOutputFilename) then
    System.Erase(DebugOutput);
  System.Rewrite(DebugOutput);
  System.Append(DebugOutput);

finalization
  System.Close(DebugOutput);

end.
```

Here, each call to the `Print` procedure saves the input string to a file called `DebugOutput.txt` located at application's root folder. Now you should save it as a file named `window.output.pas` inside a folder that Lazarus can see. For example, inside your application's root directory. Then you can add this unit to the unit's `uses` clause of your choice, in either interface or implementation, to expose the `Print` procedure, for example:

```
implementation 

uses windows.output;

procedure Foo;
begin
  Print('My debug string');
end;
```

### Option 2 - Change your app to console app and output to cmd

Go to Project->Project Options and type "win32" in the search field (at the top left of the window), then **Uncheck** the `Win32 gui application option` and you are done.

[image: Uncheck Win32 gui application option and you are done]

Comment: hello sry for a late respawns, But it does not work :  i changed all the settings accept the Build modes because i was not able to change it to Win64

Comment: The 1 Option does not work either : Compile Project, Target: project1.exe: Exit code 1, Errors: 1
○ unit1,pas(1,20) Error: llegal unit name: windows.output (expecting UNIT1)

Comment: For Option 2, you should uncheck the "Win32  gui application" option. You don't need a different buid mode.